# Bash: how to take a number from string? (regular expression maybe)

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I want to get a count of symbols in a file.

```
wc -c f1.txt | grep [0-9]
```

But this code return a line where grep found numbers. I want to retrun only **38**. How?

Comment: Did not get your question! Do you want to know the number of characters in a file f1 - the number of digits in it?

Comment: The number of characters - first number of result of wc -c f1.txt. ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use awk:

```
wc -c f1.txt | awk '{print $1}'
```

OR using `grep -o`:

```
wc -c f1.txt | grep -o "[0-9]\+"
```

OR using bash regex capabilities:

```
re="^ *([0-9]+)" && [[ "$(wc -c f1.txt)" =~ $re ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

Comment: Thank you! :) Is awk retrun all words (symbols between intervals) in defferent variables - 1, 2, 3...? And grep -o "[0-9]\+" return 38 AND 1 (at new line) from name of my file - f1.txt. How to fix thaht?

Comment: Better to use awk then. Awk will return first field in `$1`, 2nd field as `$2` etc.

Comment: or you could use wc -c f1.txt | cut -d' ' -f1

Comment: @DrakeClarris: Cut won't work correctly because of leading space in wc command's output.

Comment: @anubhava, thank you again! I do it with grep. :) I only add 1 interval at the end of regular expression to get number which have interval after himself.

Comment: Yikes...  that's how I've used it several times in my scripts and not had an issue...  couldn't you cat f1.txt into wc -c and only get one field anyways?   edit: I see that right below now.

Answer (score 8):

pass data to `wc` from stdin instead of a file: `nchars=$(wc -c < f1.txt)`